# Converting sqlite3 records to list

Tags: python, list, sqlite, tuples

I trying to convert `sqlite3` records to list with the code below but the result is output this way

```
[[1000], [1199], [1400], [1213], [1500], [1800], [1308]]
```

with the code below but i want the result to display as:

```
[1000, 1199, 1400, 1213, 1500, 1800, 1308]
```

with the `list` removed from the numbers in the `list`

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("TEST1.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT POINT FROM loyalty")
rows = cur.fetchall()

result = [list(i) for i in rows]

print(result)
```

I tried to iterate over the result this way

```
for row in rows:
    print(list(row))
```

and it outputs this way

```
[1000]
[1199]
[1400]
[1213]
[1500]
[1800]
[1308]
```

Comment: try result = [i for i in rows]

Comment: already tried that the numbers are in `tuple`

Comment: yes, sorry  result = [i[0] for i in rows]

Answer (score 0):

Each row `fetchall` returns is a tuple with each attribute from the `SELECT` indexed correspondingly, so:

```
result = [i[0] for i in rows]
```

Where `i[0]` would be the `POINT` column.

Or try iterator form:

```
for row in c.execute('SELECT POINT FROM loyalty'):
        print(row[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to get the expected result.

Following approaches can works even sublists are of odd length

rows = [[1000], [1199], [1400], [1213], [1500], [1800], [1308]]

**Most simplest approach**:

```
endResult = []
for item in rows:
    for subItem in item:
        endResult.append(subItem)
print(endResult)
```

Output: [1000, 1199, 1400, 1213, 1500, 1800, 1308]

**Another Approach to solve**:

```
import itertools
rows = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7], [8,9]]
endResult = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(rows))
print(endResult)
```

Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

**Using one of the list property (sum)**

```
endResult = sum(rows, [])
print(endResult)
```

Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

**Using lambda expression**:

```
endResult = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,rows)
print(endResult)
```

Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: @O JOE please accept the answer if this solution help u to get expected result